# How to handle "Index out of bounds" while building the data-matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a utility matrix with size `(n_users, n_items)`, but I got an `index is out of bounds` error. From the error, it is clear that I am trying to reach an element out of the matrix range, but I don't know how to form the matrix to handle this issue. If there is any suggestion I will be thoughtful to you.

Here is my code:

```
## Import the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

user_artists = pd.read_csv("./user_artists.dat", sep='\t+', engine='python')
#user_artists has three features ['userID','artistID','weight']
n_users = user_artists.userID.nunique()
n_items = user_artists.artistID.nunique()
n_users,n_items
## (1892, 17632)

## Create a user-item matrix that can be used to calculate the similarity between users and items.

data_matrix = nm.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for line in user_artists.itertuples():
    data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]
```

And this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-f3242d18985b> in <module>
      3 data_matrix = nm.zeros((n_users, n_items))
      4 for line in user_artists.itertuples():
----> 5     data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]

IndexError: index 18733 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 17632
```

Comment: There must be an error in your logic as the index is out of bounds. But if you still want to handle that you can use `try` and `except` for this. Is your logic correct?

Comment: @GHOSTHUNT Actually, I saw this approach is used before [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/comprehensive-guide-recommendation-engine-python/?#) so I think I am sure from my logic.

Comment: I won't recommend that but I've posted the answer.

Comment: @GHOSTHUNT thanks for your comment, but I really want all of the elements. If you see this approach is not appropriate, please give me a bit of advice and recommend a better one.

Comment: Why is `line[2]` 18734?  Your code shows how `data_matrix` is created, so the 17632 size is understandable.  But we have no idea of what your 'sure logic' does.

Comment: @QaddomiObaid it's not appropriate to use `try` and `except` block in this code. You have copied the from the [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/comprehensive-guide-recommendation-engine-python/) and your data is different. You have to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj I may not be sure to this level of my logic, but the subject is that I want to build a matrix its rows represent the number of unique users and its columns represent the number of unique items and if I took a sample like this: 10 is the users-ID,2 is the item-ID, and 20 is the weight. Then after making the matrix, I need to fill this position where the users-ID is 10 and the item-ID is 20 with the value 2 which represents the weight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of your logic and want to avoid this error(which isn't the solution) then do this

```
for line in user_artists.itertuples():
    try:
        data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]
    except:
        pass
```